# how to read a specific region in android emmc

Tags: android

I want to read the emmc of my device as the recovery seems to be on it.
cat /proc/mtd doesn't give any output and the deice can't be read by sp flash tool :(

What I want to do is to replace some files from CWM recovery with the stock ones (its an MTK device).

cat /proc/dumchar_info gives a table like this:

```
Part_Name   Size    StartAddr   Type    MapTo
preloader    0x0000000000040000   0x0000000000000000   2   /dev/misc-sd
dsp_bl       0x00000000005c0000   0x0000000000040000   2   /dev/misc-sd
mbr          0x0000000000004000   0x0000000000000000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
ebr1         0x000000000005c000   0x0000000000004000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p1
pmt          0x0000000000400000   0x0000000000060000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
nvram        0x0000000000300000   0x0000000000460000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
seccfg       0x0000000000020000   0x0000000000760000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
uboot        0x0000000000060000   0x0000000000780000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
bootimg      0x0000000000600000   0x00000000007e0000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
recovery     0x0000000000600000   0x0000000000de0000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
sec_ro       0x0000000000600000   0x00000000013e0000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p5
misc         0x0000000000060000   0x00000000019e0000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
logo         0x0000000000300000   0x0000000001a40000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
expdb        0x00000000000a0000   0x0000000001d40000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
ebr2         0x0000000000004000   0x0000000001de0000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
android      0x0000000020100000   0x0000000001de4000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p6
cache        0x0000000020100000   0x0000000021ee4000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p2
usrdata      0x0000000020100000   0x0000000041fe4000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p3
fat          0x0000000083f1c000   0x00000000620e4000   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0p4
bmtpool      0x0000000000a00000   0x00000000ff9f0050   2   /dev/block/mmcblk0
Part_Name:Partition name you should open;
Size:size of partition
StartAddr:Start Address of partition;
Type:Type of partition(MTD=1,EMMC=2)
MapTo:actual device you operate
```

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

As you can see, all partitions in `dumchar_info` is type 2 (=emmc, not mtd), so use `cat /proc/emmc` instead of `cat /proc/mtd".`

Anyway you might be use `MTKDroidTools by Rua1` to create a scatter file for your MTK device, then load this scatter to SP Flash Tool, click on Read back tab, then add the desired address and size of recovery partition to dump it to a file.

To find the address and size, just open the scatter file in a text editor, copy the hex number after label `revocery` (this will be the physical address in emmc), then subtract it from the next partition's address (this will be the size).

Or you can use the sizes from dumchar_info, but don't use those addresses, because those addresses are relative addresses related to the mapped devices.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get partition address of recovery of your phone. Then pull that partition using dd, unpack it using scripts by Bruno Martin, make your changes, repack, and dd it back to its address.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the partition details of emmc, then type

> cat /proc/emmc

Mtk recovery won't be listed here.

With your dumchar_info recovery is in mmcblk0 partition. You can use dd command for copying the recovery and flashing it back.

For copying the recovery partition type

> dd if=/dev/block/mmcblk0 of=/sdcard/recovery.img bs=1024 count=6144 skip=14208

You can find your recovery.img in your sdcard.

For flashing it back:

> dd if=/path_of_new_recovery_img of=/dev/block/mmcblk0 bs=1024 count=6144 seek=14208

Or

> dd if=/path_of_new_recovery_img of=/dev/recovery